# How extremely low temperatures (near absolute zero) are actually measured

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, units, low-temperature-physics

How do the industrial or laboratory thermometers for this purpose work like:

1. what effects are based on, what are other alternatives
2. how accurate they all are

Comment: @LubošMotl well you could have just edited that out ;-) In any case, there are too many things being asked here. There are probably two or three separate questions here, each of which would be a fine question on its own, but they can't be posted together.

Comment: I think that sometimes it's good to explicitly mention a tagging mistake so that others do it less often in the future. ... Can't one just list a few major technologies that are used to measure temperatures near 0K? I am a bit puzzled how it's possible that you may close the question without anyone else cooperating.

Comment: @LeonKigelman As edited it still looks very broad to me, as well as suggesting you have not done any other research.  My personal experience mostly involves [thermocouples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple).  You might learn a lot from looking through the catalog of a cryothermometry supplier, like [Lakeshore](http://www.lakeshore.com/products/Pages/TemperatureProducts.aspx).

Comment: RTDs work down to a few 10s mK eg. http://www.lakeshore.com/products/Cryogenic-Temperature-Sensors/Pages/default.aspx